# How to show only results that had positive money transfer to the bank at least once in 6 months

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to ask if you have an idea how would you get only those id´s from data which have positive money transfer to the bank at least 1 time in 6 months prior for each month for example for year 2022.

I have column date (day/month/year), id of a client and how much does he/she send money to a bank for each day(`client_cr`).  And I want that SQL looks at a client in each month (from 01/2022 till 12/2022) and checks if a client
sent money to the bank at least once in 6 moths so for 01/2022 it would check if client from 07/2021 up till 01/2022 had any transfer to the bank if so it will show in in the table and same for each month of 2022

for example:

```sql
select id,
       to_char(to_date(time, 'J'), 'YYYY/MM') time_month,
from   table x
where  to_char(to_date(time, 'J'), 'YYYY/MM') >= '2021/07'
and    client_cr???(here would be probably some clever condition which i cannot figure out)
```

It doesn't have to be the whole script even rough idea or which function I can use would be appreciated

Comment: Your question will probably get more attention if you provide create table statements and insert statements. There is a service at https://dbfiddle.uk/7Jxju0AY that can be of use. If you go that route, update your post with the url

Answer (score 0):

Does your data always have an entry of some kind for each day? Or only when there are transfers/activity and so there may be missing days?

If there it always has an entry of some kind for every day, then you can simply do:

```
SELECT id
  FROM (SELECT id,
               month,
               SUM(money_sent_count) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY month ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) money_sent_in_prev_6_months
          FROM (SELECT id,
                       TO_CHAR(datefield,'YYYY-MM') month,
                       SUM(CASE WHEN (money_was_sent) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) money_sent_count
                  FROM table
                 GROUP BY id,
                          TO_CHAR(datefield,'YYYY-MM')))
 WHERE money_sent_in_prev_6_months > 0
```

If however your table only contains transactions and so there could be missing days or whole months from an ID's history, then you will have to use a calendar table or generate one on the fly (one row per month from earliest to latest represented in your table) and outer join that to your table. If you need help doing that on the fly that'd be another question that we can help with. But once you do that, the same concept applies as above for querying for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if exists any record in the past 6 months with the same ID with positive money, try to use the idea of the query below

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.time
FROM table x a
WHERE TRUNC(a.time) >= TO_DATE('01/01/2022','DD/MM/YYYY') 
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM table x b
             WHERE a.id = b.id
               AND b.time BETWEEN add_months(a.time, -6) AND a.time --Last 6 months
               AND b.client_cr > 0) --Positive Money
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use analytic function LAST_VALUE() with windowing clause to check the last transaction month.
Sample data:

```sql
WITH 
    transactions AS
        ( 
            Select To_Date('10.01.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TXN_DATE", 101 "CLIENT_ID", 120 "AMOUNT" From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('10.03.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TXN_DATE", 101 "CLIENT_ID", 100 "AMOUNT" From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('10.05.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TXN_DATE", 101 "CLIENT_ID", 300 "AMOUNT" From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('10.07.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TXN_DATE", 101 "CLIENT_ID", -50 "AMOUNT" From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('10.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TXN_DATE", 101 "CLIENT_ID", 210 "AMOUNT" From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('10.06.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TXN_DATE", 102 "CLIENT_ID", 100 "AMOUNT" From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('10.03.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TXN_DATE", 102 "CLIENT_ID", -25 "AMOUNT" From Dual Union All
            Select To_Date('10.04.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TXN_DATE", 102 "CLIENT_ID", -30 "AMOUNT" From Dual Union All
      Select To_Date('10.10.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TXN_DATE", 102 "CLIENT_ID", 300 "AMOUNT" From Dual 
        )
```

Here is the code that looks at all previous transactions of the client checking if it was passed more then 6 months since the last one. Negative amounts are excluded by the Where clause.

```sql
SELECT 
    CLIENT_ID,
    TXN_DATE,
    TRUNC(TXN_DATE, 'mm') "TXN_MONTH",
    --
    CASE WHEN 
        ADD_MONTHS(LAST_VALUE(TRUNC(TXN_DATE, 'mm')) OVER(PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID Order By CLIENT_ID Rows Between  Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding), 6) > TRUNC(TXN_DATE, 'mm') 
        THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END  "POSITIVE_TXN_IN_6_MONTHS",
    --
    LAST_VALUE(TRUNC(TXN_DATE, 'mm')) OVER(PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID Order By CLIENT_ID Rows Between  Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding) "LAST_TXN_MONTH",
    LAST_VALUE(AMOUNT) OVER(PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID Order By CLIENT_ID Rows Between  Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding) "LAST_AMOUNT"
FROM 
    transactions
WHERE 
    AMOUNT > 0
ORDER BY
    CLIENT_ID,
    TXN_DATE
/*
 CLIENT_ID TXN_DATE  TXN_MONTH POSITIVE_TXN_IN_6_MONTHS LAST_TXN_MONTH LAST_AMOUNT
---------- --------- --------- ------------------------ --------------  -----------
       101 10-JAN-22 01-JAN-22 NO                                                 
       101 10-MAR-22 01-MAR-22 YES                      01-JAN-22             120 
       101 10-MAY-22 01-MAY-22 YES                      01-MAR-22             100 
       101 10-DEC-22 01-DEC-22 NO                       01-MAY-22             300 
       102 10-JUN-21 01-JUN-21 NO                                                 
       102 10-OCT-22 01-OCT-22 NO                       01-JUN-21             100
*/
```

Here you can see what was happening and if you want to get CLIENT_IDs with at least one positive transaction within period of 6 months you can select it from the above resulting dataset.

```sql
Select Distinct CLIENT_ID
From
    ( the above sql )
Where POSITIVE_TXN_IN_6_MONTHS = 'YES'
/*
 CLIENT_ID
----------
       101
*/
```

The same thing but with monthly comparisons in 2022. would be like below:

```sql
SELECT 
    m.MONTH_OF_YEAR,
    CLIENT_ID,
    
    TXN_DATE,
    TRUNC(TXN_DATE, 'mm') "TXN_MONTH",
    --
    CASE WHEN 
        ADD_MONTHS(LAST_VALUE(TRUNC(TXN_DATE, 'mm')) OVER(PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID Order By CLIENT_ID Rows Between  Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding), 6) > MONTH_OF_YEAR --TRUNC(TXN_DATE, 'mm') 
        THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END  "POSITIVE_TXN_IN_6_MONTHS"
FROM 
    (Select To_Date('01.' || LPAD(LEVEL, 2, '0') || '.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "MONTH_OF_YEAR" From Dual Connect By LEVEL <= 12) m 
Left Join transactions t ON(TRUNC(t.TXN_DATE, 'mm') = m.MONTH_OF_YEAR And AMOUNT > 0)
ORDER BY
    MONTH_OF_YEAR,
    CLIENT_ID,
    TXN_DATE

/*
MONTH_OF_YEAR  CLIENT_ID TXN_DATE  TXN_MONTH POSITIVE_TXN_IN_6_MONTHS
------------- ---------- --------- --------- ------------------------
01-JAN-22            101 10-JAN-22 01-JAN-22 NO                       
01-FEB-22                                    NO                       
01-MAR-22            101 10-MAR-22 01-MAR-22 YES                      
01-APR-22                                    NO                       
01-MAY-22            101 10-MAY-22 01-MAY-22 YES                      
01-JUN-22                                    NO                       
01-JUL-22                                    NO                       
01-AUG-22                                    NO                       
01-SEP-22                                    NO                       
01-OCT-22            102 10-OCT-22 01-OCT-22 NO                       
01-NOV-22                                    NO                       
01-DEC-22            101 10-DEC-22 01-DEC-22 NO                    
*/
```